# What is the interface for mounting and activating templates in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb

I am trying to create template using `session.createSchemaTemplate(template)`, and now trying to mount the template using `create session.setSchemaTemplate(templateName,"root.liot."+templateName)` command. I wonder what is the corresponding interface for mounting and activation of the template?